# VBA to compare columns in different excel files and then copy, edit

Tags: excel, vba

I am a novice with VBA and would like help on the following. Btw, I have been searching previous posts if there is same scenarion as my problem, but I've got no luck finding one. So if my problem have been solved in a different posts, can you kindly point the link.

**So here's the problem:**
I have two different excel file with one file having `Original Sheet` (3 columns) and the other with `Updated Sheet` (2 columns). I want to compare the 2nd column of `Original` with 1st column of `Updated`
Here's the tricky part, macro will search whole 1st column of `Updated` if it has the same value as of in `Original`. If there is, it will change the corresponding value of the 2nd column of `Updated` with what was written in the `Original`. If there is none, it will add the difference to end part of `Updated`.

Below is a sample of this:

**Original:**

```
1   AAAA   1111
2   BBBB   2222
3   CCCC   3333
4   DDDD   4444
```

**Updated(before macro)**

```
AAAA 1111
BBBB 2222
DDDD 5555
```

**Update(after macro)**

```
AAAA 1111
BBBB 2222
DDDD 4444
CCCC 3333
```

Hopefully, I explained it in detail. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you explained it well enough, but what have you tried to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. for each cell in Original
2. ...Found = false
3. ...for each cell in Updated
4. ........if OrigCell = UpdCell then UpdValue = OrigValue
5. ........set Found = true
6. ...next UpdCell
7. ...if Found = false then
8. ........append OrigCell
9. ........extend the range for Updated
10. next OrigCell

if you have the same value repeated in the Original (say that you have AAA twice) the line 9 will help updating the AAA value with the most recent and avoids that the same line AAA is added two times in the updated file.
I hope this helped...